# mvc 4 model, method always returning 0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I have a property in my model called BMI, it basically is some logic that returns a number calculated from a method called CalculateBMI, but this is always returning 0, even when I put a break point on the return in the method the weight and height contain numbers but the _bmi never gets assigned anything

BMI Property:

```
 private int _bmi;
        [DisplayName("BMI")]
        public int BMI 
        {
            get {return _bmi;}
            set 
            { 
                _bmi = value;
                _bmi = CalculateBMI();

            } 
        }
```

CalculateBMI method:

```
  public int CalculateBMI()
        {

            _bmi = Weight / (Height * Height);
            return _bmi; 
        }
```

Comment: There's a whole ton of weird code here. Why are you setting `_bmi = value`, then setting it AGAIN to `CalculateBMI()` and then setting it AGAIN within the actual method? I think you just want this: `_bmi = CalculateBMI()` and then in your method `return Weight / (Height * Height)`

Comment: In your setter why do you set `_bmi` to the value provided and then immediately set it to something else?

Comment: It also doesn't look like you're actually even doing anything with the `value` your BMI gets set to. You just throw it away. Why would you have to calculate BMI within the setter of your BMI property? It doesn't make any sense. You take in `value`, which is supposed to be a BMI value to begin with, and then calculate BMI with the BMI you just gave it? WHAT!?

Comment: If your `BMI` property is going to be calculated, i.e. setting it to a method call that is not dependent on the provided `value` than you should not even have a setter.

Comment: You just need to have a getter cause you are anyways calculating the BMI based on some other properties. `get{ return CalculateBMI();}`

Comment: Can you post the whole Model class?

Answer (score 2):

So I believe what we are all saying in the comments is all you need is this:

```
public double BMI { get { return Weight / (Height * Height); } }
```

@ataravati is also correct about the `DisplayName` attribute being unnecessary since it is the same as the property name.

You should also change the type to `double` since the result should be a floating point value.  I would also make sure that your `Weight` and `Height` properties are `double`s as well so you don't get zeros from integer division.

Answer (score 1):

Not looking to your code, that has some issues pointed out in other responses, you need to check your values.

A Zero resulting in a division could be from:

- `Weight` = 0
- The division result is rounded to 0, as your `BMI` variable is of type `int`

So... try debuging and do the math using the actual values. If the result is something less than 0.5 it will be rounded to 0 most likely.

You could change the BMI type to `Decimal` or `Double` to try.

Answer (score 0):

Your property should be like this, because you don't want to set it to anything. It's calculated on the fly, and you only need a read-only access to it:

```
public int BMI 
{
    get 
    { 
        return CalculateBMI();
    }
}
```

By the way, you don't need a DisplayName attribute, when the Display Name is the same as the Property Name.

Comment: apologies for the terrible code, but when I changed it to the above code it is still returning 0?